# Caching with Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, caching, memoization

I am trying to add data to a dictionary but I do not want to overwrite the whole dictionary with the new one. I want to append the new data to the old data in the dictionary.
I implemented a similar logic in Javascript using maps but I can't seem to pull it off with python. I don't know what I am missing in my logic.
Anytime I add a new data the old ones disappears. Is there a way to create a memoization or caching with python?

```py
class CacheService():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.data[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def getCount(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

---

```py
from cache import CacheService

class Action:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cache_service = CacheService()

    def add(self, args):
        try:
            with open(args) as file:
                new_data = file.readlines()
                first, last, age = [value for values in new_data for value in values.split() ]
                #check if user already exist
                self.cache_service['first'] = first
                self.cache_service['last'] = last
                self.cache_service['age'] = age
                print(self.cache_service)
        except IOError as e:
            print('Unable to Open file', e)
```

````
    from controller.action import Action

    class App():

        def add(self, args):
            make_action = Action()
            make_action.add(args)
    ```
````

Comment: this may be worth studying: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Comment: But all you're doing here is setting and getting from a dictionary. You're not doing anything to handle multiple values. JS objects work just like Python dicts in this way, so you must have done something in the JS code you're not doing in the Python version.

Comment: Good point @DanielRoseman

Comment: It's a powerful tool let me take a look at it @hiroprotagonist

Comment: Could you provide your JS code to understand more what you are trying to do?